# How to know what view triggered my ActionMode?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

Just stated learning about the ICS Actionbar. I am working with Action Bar Sherlock to be backwards compatible for things I want to do and have gone though lots of the source code on its samples.

I have 3 image views, I want to set a listener for a long click on all 3. When a user long clicks one I will show an ActionMode over the action bar letting them take a picture. Since the action bar seems to work just like the menu, how do I know what ImageView triggered my ActionMode after they click a button from it?

Don't have a lot of code done right now because I am just starting looking into it and this was the first thing I wanted to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To initiate an action mode, you need to provide an instance of the `ActionMode.Callback` class. For something like this, you should create a constructor inside this class which accepts some relevant information about the image view.

```
public static class ImageActionMode extends ActionMode.Callback {
    private final int viewId;

    public ImageActionMode(View view) {
        viewId = view.getId();
    }

    public boolean onActionItemClicked (ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        //Do something with viewId as the target
    }

    //Other callbacks
}
```

You could also keep a reference to the full `ImageView` or anything else that is what you need to respond to the options item.

Now when you start the action mode you would do something like this:

```
public void onLongPress(View view, /*whatever else...*/) {
    startActionMode(new ImageActionMode(view));
}
```

Comment: Your `public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        //Do something with viewId as the target
    }`

should that be 
`onActionItemClicked (ActionMode mode, MenuItem item)`

Comment: Is there nothing provided out of the box? It is strange.

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time on it, I have implemented it and working successfully.
At the link below, I have given correct code as well as explanation.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20369954/452487